# How did I get the Excavator badge?

Tags: support, edit-badges

The excerpt of this badge says: *Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months.*

But I am a member for just 3 months.

Don't I understand the badge explanation?

Comment: Did you edit someone else's post that was six months old at the time?

Comment: I also won the Excavator badge today, *excavator*, ha-ha-ha! Thank you SO, nice surprise! ;-)

Comment: On the other hand, on [Crypto Stack Exchange nobody yet got this badge (as there were no posts old enough)](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/badges/75/excavator).

Comment: Do we need to edit exact six months old or older than that too ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It doesn't have to be your *own* post. You could have edited someone else's post that was 6 months old.

Your [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757830/ngln) links to [information about the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1287/excavator?userid=757830) you've earned, showing that the question for which you earned this badge is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280462/lesser-known-language-constructs-of-object-pascal-delphi.

At the time of [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/280462/3), the question had been inactive since November 11, 2008, plenty more than the required 6 months. (See [all revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/280462/revisions) for comparison purposes.)

Comment: Why did I just get the excavator badge for this? It was not inactive for 6 months.