# Question about Archaeologist progress query

Tags: support, badges, data-explorer

First google result points to [**this**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69607/what-is-my-archaeologist-badge-progress) query named: *What is my Archaeologist badge progress?*

It returns `7` for me although I am quite positive I have edited more than `7`... *I may be wrong*...

So, if I go to [list of recently awarded](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist) users with that badge and pick the first and the second user IDs, I get the following results

> userID: 1380918 - result 15
>
> userID: 3339122 - result 0

This query returns some strange number IMO. I was expecting to see at last 100+ for both users who already achieved that badge.

**Is this query not accurate? Am I not evaluating this properly?**

<sub>I have seen [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124491/a-query-to-get-all-posts-that-count-for-archaeologist-and-excavator) but I don't think mine is a duplicate of it.</sub>

Comment: If those users have edited posts that were not active for at least 6 months, *then that post is has now been active more recently*. It might be that the query doesn't or cannot take that into account.

Comment: As that is essentially what Animuson says in his answer, I'd say this is *still* a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query *cannot work*; the `Posts` table in the data dump doesn't have the required information to detect what posts you edited were eligible for the badge.

At the time of edit, the post must have been inactive for at least 6 months, *but editing a post resets the last active date*. All the query can find is posts you have edited at least 6 months ago that have been inactive *since*.

You could try and see if the `PostHistory` table has enough information instead; it may be that not all activities that would reset the `LastActivityDate` column are accounted for in that table, but you could at least detect all posts you edited *at some point in the past* with that table, while the `LastEditorUserId` column in the `Posts` table will only ever reflect the most recent editor, which might not even be you.

I found a query that does just that: [Edits qualifying for Archaeologist badge progress](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/119332/edits-qualifying-for-archaeologist-badge-progress) . For your sample user ids this query returns 113 and 71 rows, respectively, so that query is a *lot* closer than the one you found. It probably should filter the `pph` subquery to certain `PostHistoryTypeId` values to be a bit more lenient as to what posts have been inactive for 6 months prior to the queried userid edit.

Comment: Thanks, so this query is silly and the 14 people who favorited it were completely wrong about their progress. Would you agree that it is not possible to check the progress on archaeologist badge using the data explorer?

Comment: This query is silly, and I cannot see any way to query how long a post was inactive before the last edit. That is ignoring the fact that if you edited a post that was inactive for 6 months, *then someone else edited the post after you*, you'd not even show up as the last editor in Posts table.

Comment: You could try something with the PostHistory table, but I am not confident that all activities that count to trigger the 'last active date' to be updated are recorded.

Comment: It all makes sense now, thanks @Martijn Pieters